# Take screenshot and save as PNG file in Windows using C program

Tags: c, windows, png, screenshot

- I want to take screenshot of windows PC(7/8.1) and file format should be in PNG format.I've found some codes that take screenshot in BMP file.
- But as I'm good at PNG file format,its good if i know that method.
- Anybody knows how to take screenshot and save that file as PNG using C language?
  Need help.
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the screen can be considered to a BMP file, you can't take screenshot in PNG.
You need to convert you BMP file to the PNG format.
Here a lib to convert to / for PNG :

http://lodev.org/lodepng/

Comment: *"As the screen can be considered to a BMP file"* - No, it cannot. It is strictly an **in-memory** representation of the pixel values. No file header information or any sort of file backing is present. It is just a raw buffer. You can save that raw buffer to any supported file format, using the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx), for example. No need for conversions, or any 3rd party libraries.